# Ductility of LK-99

Tags: material-science, conductors, superconductivity

I’ve heard about the new proposed superconductor known as [LK-99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LK-99), one thing I’m wondering that I haven’t yet gotten an answer to is how ductile is it? I.E. how easy would it be to make wires out of it?

Answer (score 1):

LK-99 is a copper-doped lead apatite. In general apatites' physical properties are somewhat similar to those of obsidian, which may be more familiar. So it's generally brittle. As for the specific properties of LK-99, [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2308/2308.03823.pdf) they are described as follows:

"Often, samples crack and break down during measurements, when high current (> 50 mA) was applied, or during mounting due to even slight mechanical vibration."

Doesn't look like good wire material.